# Roomba - IR LEDs

Tags: led, infrared, roomba

I was wondering if it was possible to create a DIY virtual wall for the iRobot roomba. Can anyone explain how I'd go about figuring out how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done that years ago just capturing the original signal from the Rumba Wall with my digital oscilloscope (but can be done for free with the PC audio card) and writing a really simple PIC program to replay the same signal with a 38Khz carrier just using NOPs and a few cycles.

I then built on a proto board a simple circuit with a PIC12F675, a transistor, a narrow beam IR led, and 4xAA NiMh cells.

30 minutes of work, and a Flawless victory :-)

I still have the code, but I'm really ashamed to show it, it really was a coding horror :D

EDIT: You asked for it, you got it. AND YOU PROMISED: No Comment... it just works. ;-)

```
list    p=12F629
    radix   dec
    include "p12f629.inc"
    __CONFIG    _MCLRE_OFF & _CP_OFF & _WDT_OFF & _INTRC_OSC_NOCLKOUT  ;Internal osc.
d1      equ     20h 
d2      equ     21h
d3      equ     22h
d4      equ     23h
d5      equ     24h
d6      equ 25h
fileA       equ 26h ;delay fileA
fileB       equ 27h ;delay fileB
filec       equ 28h ;delay fileC
pin7        equ 0   ;GP0  
pin6        equ 1   ;GP1
pin5        equ 2   ;GP2
pin4        equ 3   ;GP3 
pin3        equ 4   ;GP4 
pin2        equ 5   ;GP5 

Start   org 0x0000
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop         
    nop
    nop
SetUp   bsf STATUS, RP0     ;Bank 1
    movlw   b'10000110' 
    movwf   OPTION_REG
    movlw   b'00000000' 
    movwf   TRISIO
    call    0x3ff       
    movwf   OSCCAL  
    bcf STATUS, RP0 ;bank 0
    clrf    GPIO        
    goto    Main        
delay_1s
    movlw    0x07
    movwf    d1
    movlw    0x2F   
    movwf    d2
    movlw    0x01
    movwf    d3
Delay_0
    decfsz   d1, f
    goto     $+2
    decfsz   d2, f
    goto     $+2
    decfsz   d3, f
    goto    Delay_0
    goto    $+1
    goto    $+1
    goto    $+1
    return
do_pulse
    movlw   b'11111111' 
    movwf   GPIO
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    movlw   b'00000000' 
    movwf   GPIO
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    return
do_not_pulse
    movlw   b'00000000' 
    movwf   GPIO
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    movlw   b'00000000' 
    movwf   GPIO
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    nop 
    return
Do_1
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    call do_pulse
    return
Do_0
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse   
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    call do_not_pulse
    return
Main
    call Do_1
    call Do_1   
    call Do_1
    call Do_0
    call Do_1
    call Do_0
    call Do_0
    call Do_0

    call Do_1
    call Do_1   
    call Do_1
    call Do_0
    call Do_1
    call Do_0
    call Do_0
    call Do_0

    call Do_1
    call Do_0
    call Do_0
    call Do_0

    call Do_1
    call Do_0
    call Do_0
    call Do_0

    call Do_1
    call Do_1   
    call Do_1
    call Do_0
    call Do_1
    call Do_0
    call Do_0
    call Do_0

    call delay_1s

    goto Main

    end@
```

Comment: This sounds idea. Would you be able to share the code or signal data you discovered?

Comment: I think I still have somewhere the 'scope screenshot, tonight I'll search for it and I'll post that and/or the code. But I don't want to read NOTHING about the horrors in that program! :-)

Comment: Axeman, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here is it. I cant find the original capture screenshot, but I can make a new one tomorrow if you need it.

Comment: OH GEEZ THE HORROR (maybe).

Comment: @FakeName  Grrrrrr.... :-)

Comment: Realistically, I actually believe that it's fundamentally impossible to tell bad assembler apart from good assembler. As such, I don't think anyone here will be particularly bothered.

Comment: I almost agree with you, but there are some assembly listing that don't have excuses. like the one above... :-)

Answer (score 10):

That should be doable. The virtual wall is just a beacon using an IR emitter. We're talking about this:

[image]

So it's just an IR LED, a series resistor and a battery? Most likely not, unfortunately. The beacon will probably use a coded signal, so the the Roomba can tell it apart from other IR sources. You would have to know which IR wavelength it uses, though 950nm is a good guess. Then you need an existing Virtual Wall to record its signal with an IR photodiode and a microcontroller. Once you have the signal, that same microcontroller can send it via an IR LED.
That's worst case. If they chose for a simpler signal it would probably be a steady pulse train, like *Fake Name* suggests. In that case you can use an oscilloscope or the microcontroller to measure frequency and duty cycle. Also in that case the microcontroller is the simplest way to regenerate the signal.

> *Not everybody is convinced of this. Yet the [microcontroller](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41239D.pdf) **does not need a single external component** and the required program can be written in minutes, about the time you need to calculate the components for a 555 AMV. Accuracy: 1%. (the 1% ceramic capacitor for a 555 AMV costs almost as much as the microcontroller.) And the 555 can't do duty cycles less than 50% without yet another component. The microcontroller can do any duty cycle. Welcome to the 21st century.*

You'll need some knowledge of programming microcontrollers. The rest is just a couple of optoelectronic components, like the LED and the photodiode. And of course you'll have to borrow a commercial Virtual Wall.

Comment: I kind of doubt they do any real modulation, I would bet it's just a simple carrier. If you have a actual, retail virtual wall, use a photodiode to sniff the signal (or take it apart and probe the internals directly) with an oscilloscope.

Comment: @ElectroNoob - Can the Roomba tell the different walls apart, or do they all effectively behave the same? Is there a "wall address" or anything?

Comment: `Also in that case the microcontroller is the simplest way to regenerate the signal.` **What**? The easiest way to generate a fixed-frequency signal is a hardware astable oscillator, like the common 555. A MCU is WAY overkill, and would drag in bundles of software complexity. It basically takes something that would take 20 minutes to solder together on some perf board, and turns it into a multi-hour undertaking.

Comment: @Fake - using a [microcontroller](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41239D.pdf) it takes exactly **1 (one)** component, and you have a rectangle wave with 1% accuracy at any duty cycle you want.

Comment: @Fake - creating a signal like this is just setting a timer register. For someone who's acquainted with the microcontroller that's less than 10 minutes, maybe 5, not hours. And absolutely not "bundles of software complexity". This is 2012, not 1912, when people thought the 555 was the solution to all the world's problems.

Comment: @stevenvh As you said: `For someone who's acquainted with the microcontroller`. Otherwise, it's hours and hours of getting into quirks of the platform, looking up errata and so on. Of course, there's the support circuitry needed and a programmer. A simple timer has wide input voltage, while a microcontroller will usually require 5 V or 3.3 V input, which with itself brings more complexity such as voltage regulator and so on.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - Is a 5V supply any different from a 15V supply? I've got wall-warts here 5V/2A which are probably cheaper than the transformer you'd use for a 15V power supply. If you also use a wall-wart then we're talking about the same thing, so it's no argument.

Comment: @stevenvh I was mainly thinking about wall-warts and batteries when I mentioned power.

Comment: @FakeName, you have a point, why not write an answer that shows how to make an analog oscillator for that signal and, even better, show how to add a photodiode to cause it to sync with the roomba. Sounds like 2 great answers on this question instead of 2. I will admit that an arduino is a pretty ridiculous way to do this, it has a command to turn on the PWM and is maybe 1(2?) line(s?) of code I would write.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - Batteries are better for 3.3V than 12V or 15V, and the circuit wouldn't need a voltage regulator (doesn't the 555 frequency change with voltage. I don't know.). If we're talking about a wall-wart (batteries may not last long due to the LED), your argument doesn't count.

Comment: Sh - just for fun - Microcontrollers were available ~ 2 decades before the 21st century [One may dicker re the exact definition of the term]. 555 can do almost any duty cycle one wants "with a little care" and mayhaps a few cents of glue parts. Everyone is right (or wrong) here. FWIW: I'd start with a CD40106 [hex Schmitt inverter]and progress to a processor if needed. 555's are too limiting :-).

Comment: I've been measuring one of my virtual walls a while ago and it definitely sends out frames with data. Most frames seem identical, some are different. I don't know if it sends a unique ID or so, but it is *not* a simple square wave. Never got to look in detail at the bitstream, but it is on my wishlist.

Comment: BTW: Roomba is able to differentiate between a virtual wall and its docking station, implying there is some sort of data contained in the pulse train.

Comment: The microcontroller sounds good. I'd like to try and prototype this using an arduino. I'm not sure how I can reverse engineer the IR signals without some expensive equipment (fancy oscilloscope). Thank you all for the advice so far.